# different about onAwait And await() in kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Whats is different about onAwait And await() in kotlin coroutine, how to implement dan function in android? i have code like this

```
var value = ""
val resultEmail = async {
   viewModel.email.collect { email ->
       //get email here
       value = email
   }
}
// whats different on this method on below
resultEmail.onAwait 
resultEmail.await()
```

please help me how to using that function, thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `onAwait` and `await()` are two ways to handle the result of an **asynchronous** operation, but:

`onAwait`: This is used to specify a **callback** that will be invoked when the result of the asynchronous operation is available. It allows you to perform some action or logic with the result without blocking the current thread.
(In your codes, `resultEmail.onAwait` is used to register a callback that will be called when the result of the `resultEmail` asynchronous operation is available.)

`await()`: This is used to **suspend** the current coroutine until the result of the asynchronous operation is available. It returns the result of the operation once it is completed.
(In your codes, `resultEmail.await()` is used to suspend the coroutine until the result of the `resultEmail` asynchronous operation is available and **then** retrieve the result.)

Comment: can you give a simple implementation about method onAwait, because i'm still confusing about this, but await() method i can understand

Comment: @RiezkiMaisyar something like this? https://pastebin.com/UiR7TkCn

Answer (score 2):

`onAwait` is meant to be used in select-expressions. You can for example use it to race two different coroutines (like a `Deferred` and the first value produced on a channel). Like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun race(deferred: Deferred<String>, channel: ReceiveChannel<String>) {
    select<Unit> {
        deferred.onAwait { value ->
            println("Deferred finished first -> '$value'")
        }
        channel.onReceive { value ->
            println("Channel produced first -> '$value'")
        }
    }
}
```